# Grails : GORM : OneToMany : change name of the join column

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I'm using grails and I have an issue with database schema.
I have 2 domains : Match and Comment. A match has many comments.

(I removed some attributes to make the code readable)

Comment :

```
class Comment {

    static mapping = {
        table "comments"
        version false
        match column: 'match_id'
    }

    static belongsTo = [match: Match]
}
```

And Match :

```
class Match {

    static mapping = {
        table "matches"
            version false
            id column: "id"
            comments joinTable:
                [name: 'comments',
                 key: 'id',
                 column: 'match_id',
                 type: Long]
    }  

    static hasMany = [comments : Comment]
    //static mappedBy = [comments: 'match']

}
```

When Grails generates my database, it creates me a "comments_idx" column for my foreign key but I would like to use "match_id" that is already used for another application.

I tried some solutions I found on the web :

- Using mappedBy
- Without using "BelongsTo" but only decalre match
- Using joinTable
- Using indexColumn

But all have the same issue, it created me a "comments_idx" column instead of using my existing column (match_id)

What am I doing wrong ?
Thanks

Comment: What is the database schema you're trying to map the domain models to?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found, I just declared `List<Comment> comments` and use hasMany = [comments: Comment]... Big mistake... I removed the declaration of List<Comment> and that fixed my issue